# The points representing the complex number z for which |z + 1| < |z − 1| lies in the interior of a circle. State "TRUE" or "FALSE".

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

In other words, the distance of z from (-1,0) is less than (1,0)
|x+iy+1| < |x+iy-1|
which gives 4x < 0.
I have two questions 
1) What is the y co-ordinate? 
2) What does the interior of a circle mean? What is the co-ordinate / equation of this circle?

Comment: $x+iy$ satisfies this if $x<0$.  It is true for all $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true.

They represent a halplane determined with imaginary axis which contains $-1$, so the left side of imaginary axis.

Comment: Sir what is "halplane"?? Did you mean a 2-D plane?

Comment: Everything left from the imaginary axis

Comment: Thank you so much!!